# opencv not working on my python3.4

Tags: python, opencv, dll, dependencies

Windows XP SP2 - 32 bit
Python 32 bit.
 I installed numpy 1.9 from lfe pre built libraries and matplotlib from pip. Both works fine on IDLE (successfully imported).

I installed opencv binary from lfe as well but on importing it, an importerror occurs.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
    import cv2
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.

using dependency walker on cv2.pyd gives this msg :

Error: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in an implicitly dependent module.
Warning: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in a delay-load dependent module.

What can I do to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Build tour own OPencv Binary from source using cmake or use the standard binary available here.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-win/3.0.0/opencv-3.0.0.exe/download

the package you might be using must be broken. so use the above methods.